# pdo statement error check code

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

```
<?php
If(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name=$_POST['user'];
  require('connect.php');
  global $pdo;
  $stmt= $pdo->prepare("select name from user where name=?");
  $stmt->bindparam(1,$name);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if($row==false)
  {
    die("erorr".print_r($stmt));
  }
  elseif($row['name']==$name)
  {
    header("location: mypage.php");
  }
  else
  {
    die("please enter your user name and password");
  }
}
?>
```

error- code PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => select name from user where name=? ) erorr1 check my code help me

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is no errors.

replace

```
die("erorr".print_r($stmt))
```

by this:

```
$err=$stmt->errorInfo(); 
die('error :'.$err[2]);
```

So far, the possible problem are table (or fields) in the query does not exists, or the `$name` has no match in the table. Maybe you have to check the value in `$stmt->rowCount`

[see documentation on PDOStatement::errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)

Comment: in $err[2] can you explain here why we use 2

Comment: see the link to the official php documentation. The 2nd is the most "user readable", but add also `if (0 == $stmt->rowCount)` to handle the case "no row found"

Comment: '   <?php
     try
       {
       $pdo= new pdo('mysql: dbname=test;      host=localhost','root','ajeet');
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
   die("error". $e->getmassage());
   }
   ?>'

Comment: there is documentation for that too: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.construct.php . Compare to the example given and correct if this is not similar. Note than errorInfo() works for $stmt and $pdo if you need more info.

Comment: so, check the documentation (see link in my previous comment) and compare the string you have with the string in example (I m not sure it should have spaces, maybe the order matters, just read the doc and try to fix :) )